# Is there a master list of the Big-O notation for everything?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Is there a master list of the Big-O notation for everything? Data structures, algorithms, operations performed on each, average-case, worst-case, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/) is a fairly comprehensive list, and includes complexity (Big-O) in the algorithms' descriptions.  If you need more information, it'll be in one of the linked references, and there's always Wikipedia as a fallback.

Comment: I downloaded all the pages and made a list off every page that provides big o: https://pastebin.com/X3c7i4aF

Answer (score 6):

The [Cormen book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937) is more about teaching you how to prove what Big-O would be for a given algorithm, rather than rote memorization of algorithm to its Big-O performance. The former is far more valuable than the latter, and requires an investment on your part.

Answer (score 2):

Try "[Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)" by Cormen, Leisersen, and Rivest.  If its not in there its probably not worth knowing.

Answer (score 2):

In c++ the STL standards is defined by the Big-O characteristics of the algorithms as well as the space requirements. That way you could switch between competing implementations of STL and still know that your program had the same-ish runtime characteristics.
Particularily good STL implementations could even special case lists of particular types to be better than the standard-requirements.

It made it easy to pick the correct iterator or list type for a particular problem, because you could easily weigh between space consumption and speed.

Ofcourse Big-O is only a guide line as all constants are removed. If an algorithm runs in k*O(n), it would be classified as O(n), but if k is sufficiently high it could be worse than O(n^2) for some values of n and m.

Answer (score 0):

[Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition](http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms/), aka CLRS (Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein), is the closest thing I can think of.

If that fails, then try [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), by Knuth.  If it's not in those, you probably need to do some real research.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone, who is coming to this question from Google.

http://bigocheatsheet.com/